# Back in navigation bar without navigation controller (like Activity.this.finish() in android)?

Tags: ios, ios6

I have background in android, and in short every screen there is Activity pushed on stack, when I call Activity.this.finish() on that activity it removes from stack and app backs on previous screen (behavior like back button). In ios 6 app I have navigation bar ( it is not embedded in a navigation controller, is there any way to call something to destroy current controller and come back on previous ?

Comment: Is there a navigation controller anywhere in the hierarchy of the active view controllers, or you have no navigation controllers at all?

Comment: You need to describe how you got from the previous controller to the present one to get a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you brought the "current controller". Since there is no navigation controller involved, you might used "PresentViewController" to brought this "current controller". Then, you can "dismissViewController" as

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't reach NavigationController, you can't change it's stack.

I think you should just give your view access to NavigationController (by adding field referencing NC to view's class for example), and then just call it from wherever you want.

Also you could keep reference to NC in AppDelegate class, so you could call NC's methods from any place in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Views have no explicit relation to controllers and views cannot be in the controller stack. Set the button target to be a UIViewController instance and in the action method call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES|NO];
```